# How to list producers writing to a certain kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How to list producers writing to a certain kafka topic using kafka CLI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command line tool available that is able to list all producers for a certain topic.

This would require that in Kafka there is a central place where all producers and their metadata are being stored which is not the case (as opposed to consumers and their ConsumerGroups).

Comment: Cloudera SMM can do this using client-id and SASL auth